# Errors in Anaconda after pip install pyqt5 (or conda update spyder)

Tags: python, updates, anaconda, pyqt

In short, I can't open spyder and all the packages (as viewed in Environments) begin with 100. Trying to open spyder throws the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
>   sys.exit(main()) File
>   "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line
>   186, in main from spyder.app import mainwindow File
>   "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py",
>   line 90, in  from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py",
>   line 22, in  from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
>   ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name

I have been using Anaconda (more broadly python) for a couple months now. I was trying to install pyqt5 using the command

```
pip install pyqt5
```

it gave me an error saying something along the lines of "spyder is out of date" So I updated spyder using

```
conda update spyder
```

which seemed to work. Then I tried pip installing pyqt5 again and it worked with an error which I can't remember. The problems started after I restarted Anaconda and spyder still says it is not updated.

Thanks, 
Kelsey

Answer (score 0):

conda install -c anaconda pyqt

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, this answer could be much improved by explaining why your solution works.